# Compare values in two Collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections

I'm using a Mongo DB. Have a two collections `main_hikanshou` and `main_kokyaku`. `main_hikanshou` contains only one column - `phone_number`. `main_kokyaku` contains about 10 columns where one is same `phone_number`. This two collections have about 150000 values, I would like to compare this two collections and get `.csv` output on matched values in computational-light way...

I'm using this `js` to just to `print` it, but it takes too long for using it this way...

```js
var list = []
db.main_hikanshou.find().forEach(function(doc1){
        var doc2 = db.main_kokyaku.findOne({phone_number: doc1.phone_number});
        if (doc2) {
                list.push(doc1);
        }
    });
print(list);
```

Comment: You can use `$in` it will help to improve performance.

Comment: thanks for the comment, it returning something like this `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e059c3a122f4127b8760e99"), "phone_number" : "54345689", "phoneNumber" : [ ] }` for all values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Try this:

```
db.main_hikanshou.find({},{phone_number:1} ).toArray(function (_err, docs) {//get all phone phone numbers
    let phone_numberList = docs.map(v => { return v.phone_number });
    var doc2 = db.main_kokyaku.find({ phone_number: { "$in": phone_numberList } });//search phone 
    print(doc2);
})
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, it says `E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: db.main_hikanshou is not a function :
@(shell):1:1
`

Comment: thanks, it seems that this worked! btw. How could I export it as `.csv`? Sorry I'm new in Mongo

Answer (score 1):

Join the matching `phone_number` to the `main_hikanshou` collection using aggregate

```
db.collection('main_hikanshou').aggregate([
    { $lookup:
        {
           from: 'main_kokyaku',
           localField: 'phone_number',
           foreignField: 'phone_number',
           as: 'phoneNumber'
        }
    }
])
```